# An email to sent two people and how to distinguish "you"

Tags: email, you-all

Say I sent two people by one email. In my email, I will use **you** to refer both of them. How do I mention one? Can I use the following sentence?

> I will copy the files to you (Mr. John) and give you a good answer to
>   you (Mr. Better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using two sentences, each directed to the specific person, for example:
"Mr John, I will send a copy of the files to you.
"Mr Better, I will give you a good answer."

Note that:
"I will give you it" and "I will give it to you" mean the same thing.  You shouldn't put both in one sentence as in "I will give you it to you."

Answer (score -3):

In the norm people will reply such context in a separate email if it is not a CC’ed email.

I was not able to tell whether that context was actually meant to mean to reply to different emails using one task of a send or one person asked for two questions in one email or two people asked different questions in one email.

I would write it as per below:

Attention: Mr.John
In regard to the files that is requested, it will be sent to you shortly.

Attention: Mr. Better
In regard to the answer that is sought, it will be answered shortly.

To answer your questions: Not recommended. It will create confusion to express concision.

Edited: seeked to sought (grammar error).

Comment: "seeked" is not the past participle of "seek".  It should read "that is sought".